# Setting Debian and Windows

Tags: linux, debian, boot, windows, gnu

I have Debian. I want to run Windows on the same hard drive, but in separate partitions. I don't want to start my computer "DualBoot" (DualBoot is causing problems for the computer). what should I do? Can I press a button (choose Windows partition) at boot and enter Windows?

Answer (score 1):

But dual boot is exactly what you are referring to. Dual boot means that you have two separate oses on the same hard drive , be more specific about your problems with dual boot and maybe some help will come